Sonoma doesn't accept right password
A Mac Studio running MacOS Sonoma suddenly stopped accepting the legit user password.
No Keymap or Keyboard problems, just not accepting the password.
I have heard of a few related cases with Sonoma password problems. Any ideas?

what were those cases, and how were they solved?

By erasing the account and restoring from a backup..bad.
